# How to stop onPostExecute() of a class extends on <AsyncTask> after getting the string result?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm working with the login system of my android application that connects to the online database. If I'm going to display the result provided by the onPostExecute(), it works but if I'm going to put it on a conditional statement to do something, it's not working; or should I say, it's working but it's working infinitely.

How can I stop executing onPostExecute after getting the string result?

Anyway, here is my code:

Login.php

```
package com.example.navigationdrawerexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener, Connector.OnPostExecuteListener{
    EditText studnum;
    EditText pass;
    Button login;
    Button reg;
    TextView errorlog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        studnum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.studnum);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        errorlog = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorlog);
        login.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (arg0.getId() == R.id.login){
            ConnectivityManager conv = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo mWifi = conv.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

            if (!(mWifi.isConnected())){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enable your internet connection first!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                String student_num = studnum.getText().toString();
                String password = pass.getText().toString();
                Connector connect= new Connector(this,0,"authenticate",0,0,0,student_num,password);
                connect.setOnPostExecuteListener(this);
                connect.execute("");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if (result == "false"){
            errorlog.setText("Incorrect login information..");
        } else if (result == "true"){
            Intent goToLogInMod = new Intent("com.example.navigationdrawerexample.MAINACTIVITY");
            startActivity(goToLogInMod); //para pumunta sa login module
        }

    }
}
```

**Connector.php**
If you notice some not useful constructor parameter, just ignore it :)

```
package com.example.navigationdrawerexample;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Connector extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
    private OnPostExecuteListener onPostExecuteListener;
    private Context context;
    private int collegeactive;
    private String flag;
    private int spec_art;
    private String response;
    private int month;
    private int yr;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public Connector(Context context,int college, String flag,int spec_art,int month, int yr,String username, String password){
        this.context = context;
        this.collegeactive = college;
        this.flag = flag;
        this.spec_art = spec_art;
        this.yr = yr;
        this.month = month;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public interface OnPostExecuteListener {
        void onPostExecute(String result);
    }

    public void setOnPostExecuteListener(OnPostExecuteListener listener){
        this.onPostExecuteListener = listener;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        if (flag == "authenticate"){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{
            String link = "";
            if (flag ==  "headline"){
                link = "http://rtu-astronet.com/emag/functions.php?action=printHeadline&coll_id="+collegeactive;
            } else if (flag == "list"){
                link = "http://rtu-astronet.com/emag/functions.php?action=printArticlePerCollege&collegeid="+collegeactive+"&acadornot=1";
            } else if (flag == "spec_article"){
                link = "http://rtu-astronet.com/emag/functions.php?action=printSpecificArticle&articleid="+spec_art;
            } else if (flag == "permonth"){
                link = "http://rtu-astronet.com/emag/functions.php?action=printArticlePerMonth&month="+month+"&year="+yr+"&acadornot=1";
            } else if (flag == "authenticate"){
                link = "http://rtu-astronet.com/emag/functions.php?action=checkAccount&username="+username+"&password="+password;
            }
            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(link));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                //break;
            }

            in.close();
            return sb.toString();
        } catch(Exception e){
             return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (flag != "authenticate"){
        result = "{ \n \"Data\": \n " + result + " \n }";
        }

        if(onPostExecuteListener !=null){
            onPostExecuteListener.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you saying that after clicking the login button once, the onPostExecute() method gets called more than once?

Comment: I think so, or it's called once but the execution never ends. that's why I'm able to display the data but I can't put it on a conditional statement.

Comment: Maybe you can print out the String result in Login activity and see if it's called only once and if the value is correct. Other than that, I'm really not sure what the problem could be here.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago ie. before Android even existed.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm right , I think its about your listener , you never return false or true to your listener in onPostExecute method , but you are checking true or false value in your login activity.
i hop it helps

in your AsyncTask :

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (flag != "authenticate"){
    result = "{ \n \"Data\": \n " + result + " \n }";
    }

    if(onPostExecuteListener !=null){
        onPostExecuteListener.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

and you are check string in your login you are check true or false string

Comment: yes i know but im talking about listener onPostExecuteListener.onPostExecute(result);

Answer (score 0):

1. **Create a class file named OnPostExecuteListener**

   public interface OnPostExecuteListener {
       public void onPostExecute(String result);
   }
2. **in Login class implement the interface created in the above.**

   ```
   package com.example.navigationdrawerexample;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
   import android.net.NetworkInfo;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnPostExecuteListener {

   EditText studnum;
   EditText pass;
   Button login;
   Button reg;
   TextView errorlog;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.login);

       studnum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.studnum);
       pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
       login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
       reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
       errorlog = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorlog);
       login.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       if (arg0.getId() == R.id.login) {
           ConnectivityManager conv = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
           NetworkInfo mWifi = conv.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

           if (!(mWifi.isConnected())) {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Enable your internet connection first!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           } else {
               String student_num = studnum.getText().toString();
               String password = pass.getText().toString();
               Connector connect = new Connector(Login.this, 0, "authenticate", 0, 0, 0, student_num, password);
               connect.execute("");
           }
       }
   }

   // this method provides you the result of onPost execute;
   @Override
   public void onPostExecute(String result) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       if (result == "false") {
           errorlog.setText("Incorrect login information..");
       } else if (result == "true") {
           Intent goToLogInMod = new Intent("com.example.navigationdrawerexample.MAINACTIVITY");
           startActivity(goToLogInMod); // para pumunta sa login module
       }

   }
   }
   ```
3. **Connector class**

   ```
   public class Connector extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

   private OnPostExecuteListener onPostExecuteListener;
   private Context context;
   private int collegeactive;
   private String flag;
   private int spec_art;
   private String response;
   private int month;
   private int yr;
   private String username;
   private String password;

   public Connector(Context context, int college, String flag, int spec_art, int month, int yr, String username,
           String password) {
       this.context = context;
       this.collegeactive = college;
       this.flag = flag;
       this.spec_art = spec_art;
       this.yr = yr;
       this.month = month;
       this.username = username;
       this.password = password;
   }

   protected void onPreExecute() {
       if (flag == "authenticate") {
           Toast.makeText(context, "Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       onPostExecuteListener = (OnPostExecuteListener) context;
   }

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       try {
           String link = "";
           if (flag == "headline") {
               link = "http://rtu-astronet.com/emag/functions.php?action=printHeadline&coll_id=" + collegeactive;
           } else if (flag == "list") {
               link = "http://rtu-astronet.com/emag/functions.php?action=printArticlePerCollege&collegeid="
                       + collegeactive + "&acadornot=1";
           } else if (flag == "spec_article") {
               link = "http://rtu-astronet.com/emag/functions.php?action=printSpecificArticle&articleid=" + spec_art;
           } else if (flag == "permonth") {
               link = "http://rtu-astronet.com/emag/functions.php?action=printArticlePerMonth&month=" + month
                       + "&year=" + yr + "&acadornot=1";
           } else if (flag == "authenticate") {
               link = "http://rtu-astronet.com/emag/functions.php?action=checkAccount&username=" + username
                       + "&password=" + password;
           }
           URL url = new URL(link);
           HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
           request.setURI(new URI(link));
           HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

           StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
           String line = "";

           while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
               sb.append(line);
               // break;
           }

           in.close();
           return sb.toString();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
       }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       if (flag != "authenticate") {
           result = "{ \n \"Data\": \n " + result + " \n }";
       }

       if (onPostExecuteListener != null) {
           onPostExecuteListener.onPostExecute(result);
       }
   }
   }
   ```